# How to query for Servers from Prometheus target endpoints in Grafana variables?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, datasource, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

I have prometheus target endpoint http://10.x.x.x/9090/targets .

I  am able to see the endpoints which are scraping metrics from the node.
I want to get those endpoints  as servers in grafana dashboard dropdown. Currentyl it is being displayed as endpoints with port numbers i.e http://xyz.abc:9100 when i use the query `label_values(instance)` . I just want xyz.abc to be displayed in dropdown.

Please help.

I tried below query:
`label_values(instance)`

Comment: Is there a label where the correct name is? E.g. `host=xyz.abc`

Comment: @anemyte No, there is no label with host=xyz.abc.

Comment: Then I suggest adding one such label. What kind of service discovery do you use? If you don't know, paste one scrape job from your prometheus config into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use the "relabel_config" clause in the Prometheus, to get the "instance" label in the desired format. See more information about "relabel_config" in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config).

Anyway, you can also do the same at the Grafana tool, by using the following in the "Regex" field:

```
/^(.+):[0-9]$/
```

Comment: When i am using /^http://(.+):[0-9]$/ then i am not getting any value. I tried this /[a-z]+[0-9]+[.-]+/ but I am getting the port number again with the server name: i.e xyz1.hui.klo.gh-1:9100  . I want  xyz1.hui.klo.gh-1 in the result.  Note: There is no http:// in the beginning

Comment: I removed the "http://" from the answer (in the question you say there is it). You need to put the parenthesis to limit what you want to select in the regexp. If you don't put them Grafana will select the whole expression (with the port number).